Scene in which end of dinner is signaled by strict father placing napkin on table
My parents both remember a movie scene with the following description: A family has finished eating dinner, and two young boys are silently waiting to be excused. Their strict father places his napkin on the table, signaling the end of dinner, at which the two boys bolt from their chairs in order to go fish. 
My dad has often cited this scene as coming from the film A River Runs Through It. However, we recently watched this movie, and the scene was not present, nor was it in the deleted scenes. All IMDB turns up is that there is a slight difference in the credits in the widescreen and pan & scan versions.
Does anyone know of a cut of the movie containing that scene, or if there is another movie with a scene in which the father puts his napkin on the table and the boys run from the room?

Might it be Tree of Life? 
The impressionistic story of a Texas family in the 1950s. The film follows the life journey of the eldest son (two brothers), Jack, through the innocence of childhood to his disillusioned adult years as he tries to reconcile a complicated relationship with his father (Brad Pitt). Jack (played as an adult by Sean Penn) finds himself a lost soul in the modern world, seeking answers to the origins and meaning of life while questioning the existence of faith. 

Is this specific scene in the film? I haven't seen the film but you don't mention whether this ever occurs in it and that would help a lot!

While The Tree of Life does have a very strict father, and also stars Brad Pitt, I suspect that this is the wrong movie--though I can't be 100% sure. In part, these movies were made 19 years apart, so it seems unlikely that multiple family members world confuse them. Also, they didn't really explain a lot of details in The Tree of Life, and explaining the specifics of the father putting his napkin on the table to signal the end of dinner seems out of place. But, I haven't seen it since it came out four years ago, so perhaps I'm mistaken and I just don't remember.
